# Multicast NAT on Juniper router

Tags: routing, juniper, multicast, junos

I am trying to do source NAT on a J-series router (junos 9.2). I have two separate NAT rules setup (using security policies + source-nat interface). One is for regular unicast TCP connections and the other is for UDP multicasat. The two rules are essentially identical except the match statements. The NAT for unicast works fine, but the NAT for multicast is not working.

I am using PIM dense mode.

Do I have to do something special for multicast NAT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i havent done this yet, but maybe you need to add a:

```
service-set nat_ss {
        allow-multicast;
        nat-rules nat_rule_1;
        next-hop-service {
             inside-service-interface sp-1/1/0.1;
             outside-service-interface sp-1/1/0.2;
        }
}
```

Take a look at this: [Configuring Network Address Translation for Multicast Traffic](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/junos/junos93/swconfig-services/configuring-network-address-translation-for-multicast-traffic.html)